# How to stop playing music when the user leaves the page

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

How to stop playing music when the user leaves the page with SoundCloud container?

I get this definition of `stopAll` :

```
 stopAll = function() {
      $('.sc-player.playing a.sc-pause').click();
 };
```

But I do not know how to use it Please help me to add this.

Comment: What was first: Egg or Chicken? - If the user leaves the page, all containers are deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

I take it as you want to silence the music when user switch to another tab?

You can try this API: [`Page visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API), something like this:

```
//startSimulation and pauseSimulation defined elsewhere
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.hidden) {
    stopAll();
  } 
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

but this api gets some compatibility issues, it wont work on ie version below 10.

I used to apply a method which I don't feel very comfortable ... Use `document`'s `blur` event. It can work, but not very nice I think.

If you mean user closes the tab, then it will be the [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload) event; but I don't think you would need to silence the music if they already closed the whole page....

hope my answer helps :)